# When calling SQLFreeStmt, how to decide option (SQL_CLOSE, SQL_UNBIND and SQL_RESET_PARAMS)?

Tags: sql, odbc, unixodbc

After reading [SQLFreeStmt official document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709284(v=vs.85).aspx) many times, I still can't figure out when to use which `option`? (The good news is `SQL_DROP` is deprecated, so I can only focus on `SQL_CLOSE`, `SQL_UNBIND` and `SQL_RESET_PARAMS`).

I know the safest way is:

```
for ()
{
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, conn_handle, &stmt_handle);
    do some thing;
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt_handle);
}
```

But I think the efficiency is very low, and there should be a method to reuse the same statement handle. But after googling and reading the [SQLFreeStmt official document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709284(v=vs.85).aspx), I can't get a detailed explanation and examples about how to use which option.

For example:

```
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
SQLExecDirect(stmt_handle, query, SQL_NTS);
SQLBindCol(stmt_handle, ......);
SQLFetchScroll(stmt_handle, SQL_FETCH_NEXT, 1);
```

If I want to another SQL query with different binding columns, how should I pass option to `SQLFreeStmt()`? If I want do insert operation, how should I pass option to `SQLFreeStmt()`?

Could someone give some detailed explanations or examples? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL_CLOSE closes the cursor. You normally only need to do this if you have not fetched all the data. e.g.,

```
SQLAllocHandle (for stmt)
SQLPrepare(stmt, 'select one_col from table_with_100_rows')
SQLExecute(stmt)
SQLFetch(stmt)
SQLFreeStmt(stmt,SQL_CLOSE) # needed here because there are 99 rows left
                            # that is cursor is still open
# here might want to call SQL_UNBIND and SQL_RESET_PARAMS especially
# if the columns or parameters differ
SQLPrepare(stmt, 'select another_col from another_table')
```

If you'd fetched all the rows in the loop until you got SQL_NO_DATA the cursor is closed for you. SQL_UNBIND just removes any bound column associated with the statement. In the above example you might have bound a variable to column 1 to receive the contents of 'one_col' when calling SQLFetch. If you wanted to unbind the column so you could fetch the data with say SQLGetData you would SQLFreeStmt(SQL_UNBIND).

Your question beyond that is rather difficult to answer since other than mentioning reuse of the statement we don't know your scenario. You seem to have read the docs on SQLFreeStmt and are now looking for a way to use SQLFreeStmt when it should be the other way around.

You can reuse a statement handle to say prepare a new query simply by ensuring the statement is closed and has no bound column or parameters. I doubt allocating a new statement and freeing it at the end is an expensive operation in many drivers but you have a path to reuse if you want to avoid it.

Comment: :Per my understanding, if the statement handle is used for doing `insert`, `update` and `delete` operations, there is no
need to call `SQLFreeStmt`. `SQLFreeStmt` is only called when related `select` statement. E.g., the previous statement
is `select` with `SQLBindCol`, if I want to reuse this statement handle, I need to call "`SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE);
SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_UNBIND);`" is this right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use parameters in insert operations so you might want to call SQL_RESET_PARAMS but I don't think you absolutely need to. If you didn't open a cursor there should be no need to close the statement but be careful, e.g., returning clause etc.